# Как подружить стандартные смайлы с андроида и айфона

Tags: php, javascript, html

Подскажите как подружить сайт со стандартными смайлами которые уже есть в клавиатуре телефонов на андроиде, айос (к примеру как в интаграмм, вк тоже если вставлять смайл именно из клавиатуры телефона смайлы отображаются, нашёл коды смайлов вк, но они не такие как в телефоне) некоторые смайлы отображаются но всякие лица смех и т.д. за место них отображается ????[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как насчёт подключить библиотеку emoji.css? Это как FontAwesome только там солянка из смайликов iOS и Android. https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/